# Calculating difference from previous record

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery

May I ask for your help with the following please ?

I am trying to calculate a change from one record to the next in my results. It will probably help if I show you my current query and results ...

```
SELECT A.AuditDate, COUNT(A.NickName) as [TAccounts],
       SUM(IIF((A.CurrGBP > 100 OR A.CurrUSD > 100), 1, 0)) as [Funded]
FROM Audits A
GROUP BY A.AuditDate;
```

The query gives me these results ...

```
AuditDate D/M/Y         TAccounts     Funded                    
--------------------------------------------
30/12/2011              506           285
04/01/2012              514           287
05/01/2012              514           288
06/01/2012              516           288
09/01/2012              520           289
10/01/2012              522           289
11/01/2012              523           290
12/01/2012              524           290
13/01/2012              526           291
17/01/2012              531           292
18/01/2012              532           292
19/01/2012              533           293
20/01/2012              537           295
```

Ideally, the results I would like to get, would be similar to the following ...

```
AuditDate D/M/Y         TAccounts     TChange   Funded           FChange
------------------------------------------------------------------------
30/12/2011              506           0         285              0
04/01/2012              514           8         287              2
05/01/2012              514           0         288              1
06/01/2012              516           2         288              0
09/01/2012              520           4         289              1
10/01/2012              522           2         289              0
11/01/2012              523           1         290              1
12/01/2012              524           1         290              0
13/01/2012              526           2         291              1
17/01/2012              531           5         292              1
18/01/2012              532           1         292              0
19/01/2012              533           1         293              1
20/01/2012              537           4         295              2
```

Looking at the row for '17/01/2012', 'TChange' has a value of 5 as the 'TAccounts' has increased from previous 526 to 531. And the 'FChange' would be based on the 'Funded' field. I guess something to be aware of is the fact that the previous row to this example, is dated '13/01/2012'. What I mean is, there are some days where I have no data (for example over weekends).

I think I need to use a SubQuery but I am really struggling to figure out where to start. Could you show me how to get the results I need please ?

I am using MS Access 2010

Many thanks for your time.

Johnny.

Comment: I don't think a subquery will help you.  Upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach you could try...

```
SELECT B.AuditDate,B.TAccounts,
    B.TAccount - 
    (SELECT Count(NickName) FROM Audits WHERE AuditDate=B.PrevAuditDate) as TChange,
    B.Funded - 
    (SELECT Count(*) FROM Audits WHERE AuditDate=B.PrevAuditDate AND (CurrGBP > 100 OR CurrUSD > 100)) as FChange
FROM (
SELECT A.AuditDate,
    (SELECT Count(NickName) FROM Audits WHERE AuditDate=A.AuditDate) as TAccounts,
    (SELECT Count(*) FROM Audits WHERE (CurrGBP > 100 OR CurrUSD > 100)) as Funded,
    (SELECT Max(AuditDate) FROM Audits WHERE AuditDate<A.AuditDate) as PrevAuditDate
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT AuditDate FROM Audits) AS A) AS B
```

Instead of using a `Group By` I've used subquerys to get both TAccounts and Funded, as well as the Previous Audit Date, which is then used on the main `SELECT` statement to get TAccounts and Funded again but this time for the previous date, so that any required calculation can be done against them.

But I would imagine this may be slow to process

Answer (score 0):

It's a shame MS never made this type of thing simple in Access, how many rows are you working with on your report?

If it's under 65K then I would suggest dumping the data on to an Excel spreadsheet and using a simple formula to calculate the different between rows.

Comment: thanks for the advice. Excel is an option, but I really wanted to use Access if possible. I have 65k+ records anyway, although I think Excel 2010 can handle upto 1 million rows now ... I think. Johnny.

Comment: Don't be afraid to use this solution if it's a use-once type job on a dataset your computer can easily manage. Using a tool for the sake of using a tool when a better one exists is a blight on your time

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like the following (sql is untested and will require some changes)

SELECT

```
    A.AuditDate,
    A.TAccounts,
    A.TAccounts - B.TAccounts AS TChange,
    A.Funded,
    A.Funded - B.Funded AS FChange
```

FROM

```
(  SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY AuditDate DESC) AS ROW, 
        AuditDate, 
        COUNT(NickName) as [TAccounts],
        SUM(IIF((CurrGBP > 100 OR CurrUSD > 100), 1, 0)) as [Funded]
    FROM Audits
    GROUP BY AuditDate
) A
```

INNER JOIN

```
(   SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY AuditDate DESC) AS ROW, 
        AuditDate, 
        COUNT(NickName) as [TAccounts],
        SUM(IIF((CurrGBP > 100 OR CurrUSD > 100), 1, 0)) as [Funded]
    FROM Audits
    GROUP BY AuditDate
) B ON B.ROW = A.ROW + 1
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. Unfortunately the MS Access DB engine doesn't like 'ROW_NUMBER()'. Johnny.