# How do I compare values amongst rows on access?

Tags: ms-access, compare, rows

I would like to compare the difference in values between rows for example:

e.g. this is the original table

```
1 3 4 1 
2 5 6 2
3 6 7 4
```

I would want a result of

```
1 2 2 1
1 1 1 2
```

I know how to compare columns since it is a small number and i can directly reference them. However, my row entry will have thousands and would be impractical.

Do I need to create a for loop using the IIf function? I'm new to access and would appreciate all the help thank you.

Comment: Which field are you using to sort the dataset?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating difference from previous record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961948/calculating-difference-from-previous-record) and review http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html#AnotherRecord

Answer (score 1):

**Try if below workaround works for you**

Added 2 columns `ID1`, `ID2` as Number fields starting from 1 & 2 respectively.

[image]

**Use below Query**

```
SELECT a.N1-b.N1 As N1, a.N2-b.N2 As N2,  a.N3-b.N3 As N3,  a.N4-b.N4 As N4 from tbl as a
INNER JOIN tbl as b ON a.ID1 = b.ID2
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: @Jericho Did this help?